# Double free or corruption (fasttop) error when trying to use setter

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error

I have created a basic class object with `setter` and `getters` based on the text book. The code work fine but when I attempt to change the data in `name` from `Square` to `Circle`, I get `error : double free or corruption (fasttop)`.

Can someone enlighten me what is happening here? Is this due to some kind of memory allocation error?

Below is a reproducible code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
    protected:
        string name;
        bool contains = false;
        
    public:
        Shape(string name, bool contains)
        {
            setName(name);
            setContains(contains);
        }
        
        string getName();
        bool getContains();
        string setName(string name);
        bool setContains(bool contains);
};

string Shape :: setName(string inputName)
{
    name = inputName;
}

bool Shape :: setContains(bool inputContains)
{
    contains = inputContains;
}

string Shape :: getName()
{
    return name;
}

bool Shape :: getContains()
{
    return contains;
}

int main()
{
    Shape object1("Square", true);
    cout << "Testing" << endl;
    cout << object1.getName() << endl;
    cout << object1.getContains() << endl;

    object1.setName("Circle");
    cout << object1.getName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Interesting, when running the code in OnlineGDB without `object1.setName("Circle");` and `cout << object1.getName() << endl;` will report a segmentation fault error. What is the way to tackle this issue?

Comment: Your setName and setContains function promise to return something but don't. This is undefined behavior. Isn't your compiler throwing warnings about these lines?

Comment: When I compile it, it didn't say any error. I am using Ubuntu terminal to do this.

Comment: Set `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` to gcc or clang.

Comment: Ah. Add `-Wall -Werror` to your compiler flags.

Comment: Sorry, may I know the purpose of the command? As this is a virtual environment provided by the school, they specifically told us not to mess around with any of the setup in the Ubuntu.

Comment: If I run this in onlinegdb, the same error appear too if that helps anyone to explain to me what is going on.

Comment: You can use valgrind to better analyze and identify the cause of this issue.

Comment: The root cause is still the same: you promised to return something and did not, the program is crashing as a result. Those flags tell the compiler to check your code for common programming errors and tell you about them. Add them to the the line where you call `g++` or `clang++`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setName` and `setContains` functions don't have any `return` statements while their return types are not `void`.
Therefore, executing these functions invokes *undefined behavior*.

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.6.3 The return statement says:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

To fix this issue, you should do *one of*:

- Change return types of the functions `setName` and `setContains` to `void`.
- Add `return` statements with proper return value to the functions.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thank you, I don't really understand the second point. When you mentioned to add `return` statement with proper return value to functions, do you mean to say that I need to put the datatype in setName for the `name` and `contains` variables?

Comment: No. The variables `name` and `coutains` already have the datatype in the class declaration, so you don't need to give them the datatype again.

Comment: Thanks Mike, took me awhile but I finally understood!